# How to disable a ToggleSwitch while some async code runs in the background?

Tags: c#, xaml, async-await

When I set the ToggleSwitch, the Set property with which it's bound to in the ViewModel performs some asynchronous work. In order to avoid reentrancy problems, I decided to disable the ToggleSwitch while the work is processed.
The problem is, with my current implementation, it doesn't get disabled.

The ToggleSwitch:

```
    <ToggleSwitch Name="MyToggle"
                  IsOn="{x:Bind myVM.useCustomSound, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                  IsEnabled="{x:Bind myVM.myToggleEnabled, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The properties in the ViewModel:

```
    private bool _useCustomSound;
    public bool useCustomSound
    {
        get { return _useCustomSound; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _useCustomSound, value);
            SetCustomSoundAsync(value);
        }
    }

    private bool _myToggleEnabled;
    public bool myToggleEnabled
    {
        get { return _myToggleEnabled; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _myToggleEnabled, value); }
    }
```

The Async method:

```
    private async void SetCustomSoundAsync(bool value)
    {
        myToggleEnabled = false;

        // here I will await for some async methods to finish, for example
        await Task.Delay(5);

        myToggleEnabled = true;
    }
```

So my question again: How to disable the ToggleSwitch while the async method is processing in the ViewModel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in some way? What does SetProperty do?

Comment: Calling an `async void` from a setter is ... weird, and disadvised. You should be able to x:Bind an async method to the Toggled event.

Comment: @IsaacvanBakel yes SetProperty is raising NotifyPropertyChanged, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman but how to communicate the Toggled bool value from the xaml page to the async method in the viewmodel using x:bind?

Comment: You can simply read the value. Not sure if that will be the old or the new value but for a boolean that's easy to compensate. Try it in your mockup, this ought to work. An `async void Toggle()` should be able to take control.